# Autofocus on a input element in dropdown menu onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have a simple bootstrap navbar with a dropdown menu. The dropdown menu has an input form. The simple task I want to achieve is to focus on it with the cursor placed in the input box when the dropdown button is clicked.

I went through Stackoverflow hoping to get a solution but none of them were applicable to my specific task. I used [autofocus](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_input_autofocus.asp) attribute on the input element. It partially worked as it works first time in Chrome. But if blurred once, the cursor doesn't come back. In Firefox, autofocus attribute doesn't even work.

Second approach was triggering it manually by javascript. That too doesn't seem to work. 
Please let me know if I am doing something wrong or if there is a better approach to achieve this goal.

HTML Code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onclick="focusOnInput()">
                    Dropdown
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" autofocus>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

JS Code

```
var focusOnInput = function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu input').focus();
}
```

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/vishnuys/pen/oPebaL)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [shown.bs.dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#events) event:

> This event is fired when the dropdown has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions, to complete).

```
$('.dropdown').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $('.dropdown-menu input').focus();
})
```

```js
$('.dropdown').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $('.dropdown-menu input').focus();
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" autofocus>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Always use the events over a setTimemout.

Answer (score 2):

In the link:  a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"

Just add:

```
onclick="setTimeout(focusOnInput, 1000)"
```

instead of

```
onclick="focusOnInput()"
```

That will delay the execution of the function for 1 second, until the element is clickable....

Ofc. if you want to do it faster, change the 1000 to something else...those are miliseconds...

Good luck

Comment: Although this works, it's a mediocre hack. I suggest to go with Bootstrap's dropdown events.

Comment: For the question I asked, the above answer works well. However, I had not put the complete details of my code. For my specific case, this one works better than the above one.

Comment: @Vishnu Y S Am glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Add unique id to the input.
Ex:

And use onclick event to focus the input form.
When user click on Dropdown input focus.

```
var input = document.getElementById("D-input");
function focusOnInput() {
input.focus();
}
```

I hope it helps you.